# Plugin repository in Gradle with Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using the Gradle 8.4 with Kotlin DSL in my corporate project that runs in internal network and I have to use a private maven repository. It's easy to configure it for dependencies, but I don't see any option in Kotlin DSL to the repsitory for plugins and Gradle always try to use it's default repository in such case.

In standard Groovy syntax, there's something like pluginManagement, but I don't see it in Kotlin DSL.

How can I set the repository used to download the plugins in Kotlin DSL?

Can't find any valid option in Kotlin DSL.

Comment: @SimonJacobs, just like I mentioned before, there's no such thing as "pluginManagement" in Kotlin DSL. That's why I'm looking for other approaches specific to Kotlin DSL.

Comment: Take another look. `settings.gradle.kts` file

Comment: Argh... I've been trying to put it in the `build.gradle.kts` all the time... Thanks for pointing this out, everything looks fine now!

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine now.